# Deactivate Talk Messages on Samsung

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, google-talk

On my Samsung Galaxy S2, I am using Google Talk. I also use the preinstalled messaging app for SMS. This messaging app seams to read my Google account and shows Google Talk messages. Therefore I get Google Talk messages twice. Once in each app.

How can I deactivate receiving Google Talk messages in the preinstalled messaging app without deactivating the whole Google account on my phone?

Comment: Are you getting SMSes for the Talk messages, or is the Talk conversation just being linked from the Messaging app?

Comment: No SMSes. The messaging app "talks" Google Talk. Can not find any option to deactivate :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the latest update, the Samsung messaging app provides an option to disable Google Talk messages. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable the Talk notifications and use Messaging for everything, it should be as simple as opening Google Talk, going to its settings, then disabling IM notifications.

Comment: I want to disable IM notifications in the preinstalled messaging app. I still want to have the IM notifications in the Google Talk app. Because now I have always two notifications for the same incoming message. One from the messaging app and another one from the Google Talk app.

Comment: Why not just have all your IM happening through the built-in messaging app?  I haven't used Samsung's, myself, but it can't be any worse than the Google Talk one. :)

Comment: Samsungs messages app is buggy. After opening from notification bar, sometimes it jumps into wrong conversation. And it is very ugly. And it obviously does things I do not want. Samsung creates nice hardware, but should stop forcing their bad software on users.

Comment: Hm, then maybe there's a way of just replacing Samsung's messaging app with the standard Android one. That would kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: I think, the preinstalled apps can not be removed without rooting. And installing another messaging app does not stop the original one from running in the background and notifying about Google Talk messages.

Comment: @Witek You could try using auto-kill task managers to keep killing that preinstalled app until you find a better solution.

Comment: @Power-Inside Unfortunately, if the messaging app is getting the notification via broadcast intents, there's not a whole lot you can do to prevent the app from responding to them, due to the way intents work in Android.